# 2012r2 iis 8.5 https wont work

Tags: https, certificate, tls1.2

We have a website, that is working with http, and we are trying to get https to work.

In the iis the certificate is installed and the Bindings are set.
According to the certificate vendor, everything is correct in iis (They have checked)

But when trying to connect from a browser i get "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"

I did a networktrace on the server and i can see the browser making a SSLHandshake, thats semms OK

But the server answer says

Http: Response, HTTP/1.1
ProtocolVersion: HTTP/1.1
StatusCode: 400, Bad request
Reason: Bad Request

i can altso see in the hex details, Bad Request - Invalid Verb

Anyone have any idea what can be wrong?

Thanx Martin

Answer (score 0):

OK, i did solve it

When adding the new portforwad rule for https i copied the http rule, but missed to change the port on the server side, so all communcation got port translated from 443 to port 80 on the server side

/Martin